# LWC dynamically render components and call method for each

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, parent-to-child

I have a parent lwc component and child lwc component.I need for each  item in dataList display child component and then call method for each child component. How can I do it via lwc? Its easier via aura with dynamic component creation. And alert(childElements.length) displays 0 on  first apiParentMethod, but display some number on each future call. I need to rerender it or change the logic somehow.

Actually I dont need an dataList property and using it just for loop.

parent.js

```
   @api apiParentMethod(dataList) {
       apiParentMethod.forEach(data=> this.parentMethod(data,data.type));
   }

   parentMethod( data, type) {

       let dataObject= {
          type:type,
          data:data
       }
       this.dataList.push(dataObject);
       this.dataList= [...this.dataList];
       let childElements = this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child');
       alert(childElements.length);  
    }
 }
```

parent.html

```
<template>
    <template for:each={customToasts} for:item="customToast">
        <c-child key ={data.list} for:item="data"/>
    </template>
</template>
```

child.js

```
@api childMethod(data,type) {
    alert(data);
    alert(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for a render cycle asynchronously:

```
   async parentMethod( data, type) {
       let dataObject= {
          type:type,
          data:data
       }
       this.dataList.push(dataObject);
       this.dataList= [...this.dataList];
       await Promise.resolve(); // wait for a render cycle
       let childElements = this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child');
       alert(childElements.length);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderedCallback()

doc - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered

parent.js

```
renderedCallback() {
    console.log(this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child').length);
}
```

Thanks